# How to set the major-mode for edit babel src block in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, graphviz, org-mode, dot, org-babel

I try to use <kbd>C-c '</kbd> to call `org-edit-src-exit` to edit "dot" source code. How could I make `graphviz-mode` the default major mode on that source code editing buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mode for Graphviz is `graphviz-dot-mode`, and it can be installed from MELPA or Marmalade. After that you can specify the mode in the source block like usual:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC graphviz-dot
...
#_END_SRC
```

Answer (score 3):

I have this in some old files, but I'm not currently using any of it so you'll have to research if it works or if you can fix it to apply here.

```
(add-to-list 'org-src-lang-modes '("dot" . graphviz-dot))
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((dot . t)
   (emacs-lisp . t)
   (latex . t)
   (sh . t)
   ))
```

Be sure to use `C-h f` = `M-x describe-function` and `C-h v` = `M-x describe variable`, if you're not already familiar with them. (With cursor on (or to the right of?) expression Emacs will guess what term you mean.) It may help you discover the solution given clues.